# How to get process PID started by Symfony?

Tags: php, linux, symfony, pid, symfony-process

How can I get PID of process started by Symfony?
The code bellow

```
$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process('vlc');
$process->start();
return $process->getPid();
```

returns PID 1488. But there is no process (no vlc, no php) in system with same PID.

#### Edit

Presented code runs in app/console (Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command)

Comment: Have you read this ? http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/03/test-symfony2-commands-using-the-process-component-and-asynchronous-assertions/

Comment: I dont want to create the file. I need to get directly PID of the started process when it starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Process forking

It's not unlikely for processes to spawn off their UI separately and letting the starter process end normally, i.e.

```
----> vlc (1488) ---> EOL
       |
       +--> vlc-ui (??) ---> Application
```

This behaviour is observable by running the application from the command line and checking whether the prompt returns almost immediately.

#### Hangup signal

Also note that when a parent process exits (your script), the child process may choose to also exit by listening to SIGHUP signals. If you're not doing so already, you could let your script "live" longer by adding a `sleep()` statement while you investigate.

Comment: I will try with another app.
UPD: I ran the 
ezstream -c /abs_path_to_cfg.xml
Same result.

Comment: The Symfony component you're using should already encapsulate that.

Comment: Nope. I just watching sources:
`$this->process = proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $this->env, $this->options);`
$commandline is unchanged from constructor.

Comment: @Konpaka [This](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php#L1327) is where `proc_get_status()` is called ...

Comment: I forget to check getPid(), my bad. Thank you for reply, I will try to see tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that may work in some situations is doing it inversely like a script to grep parse a 'ps -A' containing the desired process (PHP e.g.) and rip off PID from the result. You don't have control on "who's who" on the result set but have control on "who's" actually running.

Comment: Sure I know about this. Thanks.